# W10: automatically arrange apps on the screen - something like kiosk mode with split screen

Tags: windows, kiosk

I have some touchscreens in semi-public area where I need to display a webbrowser (probably edge, firefox or chrome) and a second application. Both Apps should start with a specific windows size and position and in best case are not resizable or movable. 
One scenario would be to resize and move the apps by some softawre.
The second scenario would be to imitate that there are two monitors connected (split screen) and start both apps in full screen mode. This would be even better, as it would enable the start of the webbrowser and the second app in fullscreen (F11) mode or even in kiosk mode.
I have already tested UltraView Desktop Manager, but the fullscreen (F11) mode ignores the split screen.